# If attribute is nil then use defaults from hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a model that merges a `@lead` with some default values like so:

```
DEFAULTS = {
  inflation: 4.224 / 100,
  usage: 12_000, 
  cost: 3250
}.freeze

@lead.attributes.symbolize_keys.reverse_merge!(DEFAULTS)
```

This half works but it won't use the `DEFAULT` usage if the `@lead` usage is `nil`. How can I apply `DEFAULT` values to the `@lead` *only* if the `@lead`'s value is `nil`?

I don't want to store defaults in the migration for a number of reasons so that's out.

Thanks.

Comment: have you had a look at the block version of [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge)? e.g. `@lead.attributes.symbolize_keys.merge(DEFAULTS) { |key, old_val, new_val| old_val.nil? ? new_val : old_val }` btw `reverse_merge!` with the `!` (bang) will not have any impact since the chain created by `attributes.symbolize_keys` I believe is a copy not a reference

Comment: That worked great, thanks!

Comment: I would write the block as `{ |_, old_val, new_val| old_val || new_val }`

Answer (score 0):

```
DEFAULTS = {
  inflation: 4.224 / 100,
  usage: 12_000, 
  cost: 3250
}.freeze

if !@lead
    @lead.attributes.symbolize_keys.reverse_merge!(DEFAULTS)
end
```

The `!` operator will make @lead eq fals when @lead is nil and otherwise make it eq true.

Comment: You didn't understand the question, I'm afraid. In your defense, it's very confusingly worded.

Comment: `unless` is more idiomatic than if..not or `if !x` that being said as @SergioTulentsev pointed out this was not the purpose of the question